# Need help: Although one or more Error Occurred [execution reverted] Contract Execution Completed

Tags: error

iam not able to import this token into metamask. It will be found but after import its not showing up. It seems there is a problem. This is my second buy of a coin. And i need help.

https://etherscan.io/tx/0x4b10f231a847b91913a38b6aced3c1a4777d9b7f85cb9867dfe6df33944ea55e

Comment: this is a transaction has, not an address iiuc - the contract addr _might_ be 0x1aE9f52f421AF58e71fB9C6f36A74DEb9a68E144 based on the tx?

Answer (score 0):

About the error message: Although one or more Error Occurred [execution reverted] Contract Execution Completed.

As stated, there are errors that appeared in the transaction. It can be due to lots of factors, i.e., callback data, etc. However, if you do not care about technical things, just pass it, because the transaction still works.

About the token adding in Metamask:

Basically, you just need to reset the Metamask and then, you can easily import the token again. Just remember to select custom tokens as below

[image]

Then, it should work as

[image]